# How to filter data in query with multiple CROSSJOINs by a flag value

Tags: mdx, cognos

I have a query with a multiple CROSSJOIN on rows and columns I want to filter all data `[Measures].[Flag] = 1`
Here is an example:

```
SELECT 
  {
    NonEmpty
    (
      CrossJoin
      (
        {
          [Time].[2016]
         ,[Time].[2017]
        }
       ,CrossJoin
        (
          {
            [Quarters].[2 Quarter]
           ,[Quarters].[1 Quarter]
          }
         ,{
            [Measures].[Load]
           ,[Measures].[Flag]
          }
        )
      )
    )
  } ON ROWS
 ,{CrossJoin([Industry].[Industry 1],[Client].[Set 1])} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE 
  [Version].[Actual];
```

If I do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  {
    NonEmpty
    (
      CrossJoin
      (
        {
          [Time].[2016]
         ,[Time].[2017]
        }
       ,CrossJoin
        (
          {
            [Quarters].[2 Quarter]
           ,[Quarters].[1 Quarter]
          }
         ,{
            [Measures].[Load]
           ,[Measures].[Flag]
          }
        )
      )
    )
  } ON ROWS
 ,{
    Filter
    (
      CrossJoin
      (
        [Industry].[Industry 1]
       ,[CLient].[Set 1]
      )
     ,
      [Measures].[Flag] = 1
    )
  } ON COLUMNS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE 
  [Version].[Actual];
```

I get an empty set. In a result set witout a filter there is data with `Flag = 1`

Comment: I think that filter will be doing the sum of `[Measures].[Flag]` for each column - if the sum is 1 then is keeps the column ... but I suspect each `[Measures].[Flag]` column is more than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have found a solution to this problem. The fix is to use filter differently. Here is an example:

The big thing to notice here was that 'Flag' data was available in specific dimension configuration.

```
SELECT 
  {
    NonEmpty
    (
      CrossJoin
      (
        {
          [Time].[2016]
         ,[Time].[2017]
        }
       ,CrossJoin
        (
          {
            [Quarters].[2 Quarter]
           ,[Quarters].[1 Quarter]
          }
         ,{
            [Measures].[Load]
           ,[Measures].[Flag]
          }
        )
      )
    )
  } ON ROWS
 ,{
    Filter
    (
      CrossJoin
      (
        [Industry].[Industry 1]
       ,[CLient].[Set 1]
      )
     ,
      (
       [Cube].(
               [Time].[2016],
               [Quarters].[1 Quarter],
               [Measures].[Flag]
              ) = 1
      )
    )
  } ON COLUMNS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE 
  [Version].[Actual];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just move it into a HAVING clause does that help?

```
SELECT 
  {
    NonEmpty
    (
      CrossJoin
      (
        {
          [Time].[2016]
         ,[Time].[2017]
        }
       ,CrossJoin
        (
          {
            [Quarters].[2 Quarter]
           ,[Quarters].[1 Quarter]
          }
         ,{
            [Measures].[Load]
           ,[Measures].[Flag]
          }
        )
      )
    )
  } ON ROWS
 ,
      CrossJoin
      (
        [Industry].[Industry 1]
       ,[CLient].[Set 1]
      )
     having [Measures].[Flag] = 1 ON COLUMNS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE 
  [Version].[Actual];
```

Comment: I have tested this. Having gives me syntax error on Cognos TM1.

Comment: @Mindaugas I found this in respect of using HAVING in Cognos: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014464971

Comment: I have found a solution. I had to use filter differently.